# I am adding loading effects on ajax processing.. its working fine in mozilla but css not working in chrome

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I am adding loading effects through css.. its working properly for mozilla but not working for chrome.. effects are not looking during page load for chrome.

My css code snippet:

```
.loadersmall {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
    border-color: #B6E8FA #00ADEE #00ADEE;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 251px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Use In jQuery:

```
$("form#photodata").submit(function(e){ 
         $('.loadersmall').show();
         $.ajax({ 
               ................
               success: function (data1) { 
                  $('.loadersmall').hide(); 
               }  
         }) 
});
```

please suggest the changes to work loading css in chrome also.

Comment: Can I see your `ajax function`, post also your sample code in ajax

Comment: did you try without -moz- prefix?

Comment: You need to use -webkit for chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use the below modified styles. You need to use prefixes for chrome.

```css
.loadersmall,
.loadersmall:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.loadersmall {
  margin: 60px auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  border-top: 5px solid #00ADEE;
  border-right: 5px solid #00ADEE;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #00ADEE;
  border-left: 5px solid #B6E8FA;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
  animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loadersmall"></div>
```

Comment: are you using javascript to load this loader? share it if yes

Comment: $("form#photodata").submit(function(e){ 
         $('.loadersmall').show();
         $.ajax({ 
               ................
               success: function (data1) { 
                  $('.loadersmall').hide(); 
               }  
         }) 
});

Comment: open the developer tool and check the console whether you getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following,

```
.loadersmall { 
    border-bottom-colors: none;
    border-left-colors: none;
    border-right-colors: none;
    border-top-colors: none;
    animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running spin;
    border-color: #B6E8FA #00ADEE #00ADEE;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 251px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```